# How to write to a cell of an asp:table using loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, html-table, cells

I was wondering if its possible to write to a specific cell of an asp:table using a loop in asp.

e.g.

ASPx File

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label>Week</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="lecWeekDD">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="4" Value="4" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="5" Value="5" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="6" Value="6" />      
                            <asp:ListItem Text="7" Value="7" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="8" Value="8" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="9" Value="9" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="11" Value="11" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="12" Value="12" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            <<asp:Table runat="server" ID="lecTimetable">
                <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell Text="Week/Period" />
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P1 (09:00-10:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P2 (10:00-11:00"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P3 (11:00-12:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P4 (12:00-13:00"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P5 (13:00-14:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P6 (14:00-15:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P7 (15:00-16:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P8 (16:00-17:00)"/>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="P9 (17:00-18:00)"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="Monday"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell Text="Tuesday"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="Wednesday"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
                 <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell Text="Thursday"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell Text="Friday"/>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
```

And Code Code Behind

```
public partial class Lecturer1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["currentUser"] != null)
            {
                // lbl1.Text = "Welcome " + Session["currentUser"].ToString();


                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UsersConnectionString"].ToString());
                con.Open();

                string day = "";
                int period;



                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
                {
                    if(i==1){
                        day = "Monday";
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        day = "Tuesday";
                    }
                    else if (i == 3)
                    {
                        day = "Wednesday";
                    }
                    else if (i == 4)
                    {
                        day = "Thursday";
                    }
                    else if (i == 5)
                    {
                        day = "Friday";
                    }

                    for (int j = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                    {
                        period = j;
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Request].moduleCode FROM [Request] INNER JOIN [BookedRoom] ON [Request].requestID = [BookedRoom].requestID INNER JOIN [Modules] ON [Request].moduleCode = [Modules].moduleCode INNER JOIN [Week] ON [Request].requestID = [Week].requestID  WHERE [Week].week = "+lecWeekDD.SelectedValue.ToString()+" AND [Request].day = '"+day+"' AND [Request].periodStart =  "+period+" AND (SELECT [ModuleLecturers].lecturerID FROM [ModuleLecturers] INNER JOIN [Modules] ON [ModuleLecturers].moduleCode = [Modules].moduleCode WHERE [Request].moduleCode = [Modules].moduleCode) = '"+Session["currentUser"]+"'" , con);
                        SqlDataReader reader;
                        reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {

                                lecTimetable[i][j].text;
                                //testBox.Text =  reader.GetString(0);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //testBox.Text = "nothing found";
                        }

                        reader.Close();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Would it be possible to write to the table by using its ID with the row and column i.e. `lecTimetable [ i ] [ j ].text = .........`?

Comment: you need to assign the result to a datatable lecTimetable?

Comment: not a database table, just a normal table e.g a gridview table but dont worry I've fixed it now

Answer (score 0):

You can do lecTimetable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = .....

But you'd have to create cells before you do that (using lecTimetable.Rows[i].Cells.Add(...)). So you can do something like

```
var row = lecTimetable.Rows[i];
...
...
var cell = new TableCell();
row.Cells.Add(cell);
...
...
lecTimetable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Text = ...
```

Noticed that you have a minor mistake in your looping - your inner loop uses the variable I. I presume it should be j

```
for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
```

**Edit** : noticed that you've already added the rows (but not all the cells) - removed that section of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, yeah I figured out after I posted it, surprisingly it worked even with that error